# scrapy request form for scraping data

Tags: html, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using this code and i am using url=http://money.moneygram.com.au/forex-tools/currency-converter-widget-part

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
#import __init__
#from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.http import Response
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import MySQLdb
class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "moneygram"
    allowed_domains = ["moneygram.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://money.moneygram.com.au/forex-tools/currency-converter-widget-part"]

    def parse(self,response):
           # yield FormRequest.from_response(response,formname='firstSelector',formdata="FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR&FromCurrency_dropDown=USD&ToCurrency_dropDown=INR",callback=self.parse1)
           # request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://money.moneygram.com.au",
           #                    cookies={'FromCurrency': 'USD', 'ToCurrency': 'INR'},callback=self.parse1)

            yield FormRequest.from_response(response,formname=None,formnumber=0,formpath=None,formdata="FromCurrency=AED&ToCurrency=VND&FromCurrency_dropDown=AED&ToCurrency_dropDown=VND&FromAmount=2561&ToAmount=&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest",callback=self.parse1)
```

To send the form data as required to me but is giving error that

```
raise ValueError("No <form> element found in %s" % response)
exceptions.ValueError: No <form> element found in <200 http://money.moneygram.com.au/forex-tools/currency-converter-widget-part>
```

How can I convert from usd to inr ?

Answer (score 0):

The page you mentioned is not a valid HTML. Looks it's a SSI block which should be part of another page.

You the error because This page uses Javascript heavily. It doesn't have a 
[`FormRequest.from_response`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response) tries to make the request using an existing form, but the form is not there.

You should either work with the whole page, or make up the `FormRequest` filling it's attributes manually and then submitting it to the URL from the whole page.

Comment: https://www.moneygram.com/wps/portal/moneygramonline/home/estimator?LC=en-US this is the link now please tell me how to pass the form taking values united states to india please help me out i have to extract exchange rate..